# arrange by weeks, sql and coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I want to get the list of employees(vertically) and their work done arranged by weeks(horizontally), so far i've managed to write this code:

**sql code**

```
SELECT EP.EMPLOYEE_ID,EP.EMPLOYEE_NAME,EP.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME,WEEK=DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1,
    WORKS=SUM(CASE WHEN PW.WORK_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM EMPLOYEE_POSITIONS EP
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PRO_WORKS PW ON PW.PROJECT_EMP_ID=EP.EMPLOYEE_ID
    WHERE EP.POSITION_STATUS=1 AND DATEPART(MM,PW.RECORD_DATE)=#attributes.month# AND DATEPART(YY,PW.RECORD_DATE)=#session.ep.period_year#
    GROUP BY EP.EMPLOYEE_ID,DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1,EP.EMPLOYEE_NAME,EP.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME
    ORDER BY EP.EMPLOYEE_NAME,EP.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME
```

**output**

```
<cfoutput query="get_works" group="employee_id">
        <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row">
            <td>#EMPLOYEE_NAME# #EMPLOYEE_SURNAME#</td>
            <cfoutput>
                <td>#WORKS# - #WEEK#</td>
            </cfoutput>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
```

The output of this, is repeated the list of employees and repeated jobs done by weeks.
What im doing wrong?

Thank you all for the help!

UPDATE: i've changed the code, now there is a problem with null values, there are no zeroes values :(

Comment: The group attribute of cfoutput might be helpful.  Make sure your query has an order by clause.

Comment: @DanBracuk i've used it, for both, for first group="employee_id" for the second group="week" didnt help... the zero values are not seen, even if i use coelesence

Comment: Well that is what should happen. `Coalesce` is not a magic bullet. It does not *add* missing records. If your JOIN returns one record ("Apr 2"), instead of three ("Apr 2", "Apr 3", "Apr4"), `coalesce` is not going to change that. As you discovered, you either need a pivot (which you said is not supported in your version) OR a `case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've managed to solve my question by arrangin each week in month by this way:

```
SELECT EP.EMPLOYEE_ID,EP.EMPLOYEE_NAME,EP.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME,
    WEEK1=SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    WEEK2=SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1)=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    WEEK3=SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1)=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    WEEK4=SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1)=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    WEEK5=SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1)=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    WEEK6=SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, PW.RECORD_DATE), 0), PW.RECORD_DATE) +1)=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM EMPLOYEE_POSITIONS EP
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PRO_WORKS PW ON PW.PROJECT_EMP_ID=EP.EMPLOYEE_ID
    WHERE EP.POSITION_STATUS=1 AND DATEPART(MM,PW.RECORD_DATE)=#attributes.month# AND DATEPART(YY,PW.RECORD_DATE)=#session.ep.period_year#
    GROUP BY EP.EMPLOYEE_ID,EP.EMPLOYEE_NAME,EP.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME
    ORDER BY EP.EMPLOYEE_NAME,EP.EMPLOYEE_SURNAME
```

and output:

```
<cfoutput query="get_works">
        <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row">
            <td>#EMPLOYEE_NAME# #EMPLOYEE_SURNAME#</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">#week1#</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">#week2#</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">#week3#</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">#week4#</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">#week5#</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">#week6#</td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a [cross tab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_tab) or [pivot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) query.  Excel users are very familiar with this and usually like their data in this format.

Try putting your query result as the following, using SQL-Server's PIVOT [[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx%5d) function, then output the resulting set.  For your table headers, you can use the COLUMNLIST function.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but link says: Content not found :( and the pivot doesnt work in our sql